# VBA Copy Paste Special

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I am trying to copy a range of cells from Sheet "Stream" to the Sheet "General".
Somehow my paste function is not working. Any hint?

```
    Stream.Range("F103:J103").Copy  General.Cells(General.Range("F2:J2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=_False, Transpose:=False)
```

Comment: How is your code not working? Does it paste anything at all?

Comment: No idea why. I get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Sheets("Stream").Range("F103:J103").Copy
 Sheets("General").Range("F2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

For value pasting, you need to first copy the range and then paste to destination.
Also you have to use Sheets() to identify different sheets.